# How do I set Numbers 1,2,3 to child table data using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My query look like this

```
        select 
        SKU+'_'+'Attribute' as AttributeName,
        SKU as AttributeCode,
        SKU as AttributeKeyName,
        'Select Colors' as AttributeDisplayName,
        sc.PRIMARYOMSCODE as  AttributeValueName,
        cl.PMSCOLOR as AttributeValueCode,
        cl.RGBCOLOR as AttributeValueKeyValue,
        scl.NAME as AttributeValueDisplayName,
        '' as AttributeValueDisplayOrder,



        SKU+'_'+sc.PRIMARYOMSCODE+'.png' as AttributeValueImageName,
        'All' as AttributeValueCategory,
        'FALSE' as IsHideInpreview

         from con.style s 
        inner join con.styleColor sc on s.STYLEID = sc.STYLEID
        inner join con.color cl on sc.PRIMARYCOLORID = cl.COLORID
        inner join con.styleColorLanguage scl on scl.STYLECOLORID = sc.STYLECOLORID
        where s.SKU in ('805B3','804DK','802ZW') and sc.DELETEIND= 0
```

Expected Result 
I am expecting a result like below highlighted column. Can you please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do this in MSSQLSERVER, you'd use the ROW_NUMBER function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql

In your case,

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AttributeCode ORDER BY AttributeName (or anything else)) AS AttributeValueDisplayOrder...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() window function.

Add a new column:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY SKU) AS AttributeValueDisplay
```

There is no order in your query, if you need to order results add corresponding field after `ORDER BY SKU, AnotherField`

Comment: NOTE that `ORDER BY..` in the query is not related to the `OVER (ORDER BY...)` in the window function. `ROW_NUMBER()` follows the `OVER(ORDER BY...)` ordering.  >>> https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-2012-window-function-basics/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the tag says SQL_Server, but for a future reader, if using MySQL, this solution should work:

From http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

You could try something like:

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT
  ...
  (((@row_number:=@row_number + 1) mod 7) + 1) AS AttributeValueDisplayOrder,
  ...
```

`@row_number` is being incremented, then divided by 7 and remainder taken, then 1 added (so you have 1..7 rather than 0..6)

P.S. mind the `;` in the first line, it's important.

Comment: Question is about SQL-Server

Comment: You may be right, it wasn't clear from the question itself, I only checked the tags after your comment. I've updated my answer.